# document.evaluate to evaluate Xpath on HTML produced in-browser by XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath

I have been making a simple XSLT stylesheet in order to transform an XML log into a more easily readable HTML output. The early stages went fine and the log is displayed nicely. However, I then tried to implementing a search function and I was aiming to use Xpath for this, because it allows a decent amount of control vs a simple text search.

The search function I wrote is below, but I ran into some strange behaviour. It doesn't work if I directly open the XML file with the browser and have the HTML generated from that using the XSLT file. However, if I copy the generated HTML out of the browser into a file, the search function works exactly as expected, and I am able to filter the output.

searchScript.js

```
function searchFunction()
{
  var animals, animal, searchBox, filter;

  searchBox = document.getElementById("searchBox");
  animals = document.getElementsByClassName("animallist");

  filter = searchBox.value;

  //No idea why this only works on exported HTML not directly on styled XML...
  var toShow, toHide;
  var nsResolver = document.createNSResolver( animals[0].ownerDocument == null ? animals[0].documentElement : animals[0].ownerDocument.documentElement );
  toShow = document.evaluate("//div[@class='animal']/div[@class='animaldata' and boolean(" + filter +")]/..", document, nsResolver, XPathResult.    UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  toHide = document.evaluate("//div[@class='animal']/div[@class='animaldata' and not(" + filter +")]/..", document, nsResolver, XPathResult.    UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

  for(var i=0, len = toHide.snapshotLength; i < len; i++)
  {
    toHide.snapshotItem(i).style.display = "none";
  }
  for(var i=0, len = toShow.snapshotLength; i < len; i++)
  {
    toShow.snapshotItem(i).style.display = "";
  }

}
```

I have recreated a simpler situation below which exhibits the same issue. A list of farm animals that should be searchable. Again, doesn't work if I open the XML file, does work if I copy the generated HTML from within the browser, save to file and open that.

farm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="searcher.xsl"?>
<Farm>
<Animal>
<Name>Carl</Name>
<Status Age="3">Healthy</Status>
<Species>Pig</Species>
</Animal>
<Animal>
<Name>Bob</Name>
<Status Age="7">Healthy</Status>
<Species>Horse</Species>
</Animal>
<Animal>
<Name>Paul</Name>
<Status Age="15">Unwell</Status>
<Species>Donkey</Species>
</Animal>
<Animal>
<Name>Anne</Name>
<Status Age="1">Healthy</Status>
<Species>Hen</Species>
</Animal>
</Farm>
```

searcher.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
      <meta name="description" content=""/>
      <meta name="author" content=""/>

      <title>Farm Viewer</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-    Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

      <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
      <link href="resultview.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>

    <body>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Farm Viewer</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-    expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="XPath Search Query" aria-label="Search" id="searchBox"/>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="searchFunction()">Search</button>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <main role="main" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1>Farm Viewer</h1>
          <p class="lead">
            This viewer displays and allows searching of the XML Farm<br/>
            <br/>
            The search bar at the top enables complex searches and queries to be carried out using the Xpath language<br/>
            For instance, in order to only display healthy animals, the simple query <i>.//Status='Healthy'</i> can be used.<br/>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="animallist">
          <xsl:for-each select="Farm/Animal">
            <div class="animal">
              <div class="animaldata">
                <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
              </div>
              <h2><xsl:value-of select="Name"/> the <xsl:value-of select="Status/@Age"/>y.o. <xsl:value-of select="Species"/> is <xsl:value-of     select="Status"/>.</h2>
            </div>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>

      </main>

      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
      ================================================== -->
      <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-    KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-    ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-    a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!--Script to search the document-->
      <script src="searchScript.js"></script>

    </body>
  </html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

resultview.css

```
body {
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
}
.animaldata{
    display:none;
}
#searchBox{
    width:100%;
}
```

I'm using the latest Firefox, and this is purely for local use viewing log files, so I don't want any serverside solutions.

I'm not too familiar with web development, so its likely this could be something pretty simple. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to remove the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` and then to change `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>` to `<xsl:output method="html" version="5" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>`. That way your XSLT creates HTML output and not XHTML and you probably find the XPath works while I think with XHTML Firefox would require you to set up a prefix for the XHTML namespace to be used in your XPath expressions.